# How will you pass arguments more than one time to Thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `HashMap` of String(key) , ArrayList(value). And 5 threads of `MyThread` class. I want to pass each thread A `Arraylist` more than one time. No. of `ArrayList` that I pass  can be 2,3,4,5 times so on. How will I pass `MyThread` class a parameter more than one time so that it can process it, in its run method every time I pass the `ArrayList`.

Run method

I tried to find the solution But couldnt find anything usefull.

Comment: Use [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Send elements by using `put`/`offer` and receive in Thread using `poll`/`take`

Comment: How will I use it? I need run method to work on first arraylist. When It is done with it I want run method to process it with 2nd arraylist which will come as a parameter from my main.

Comment: Please can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by passing a an ArrayList multiple times to the Thread class? You could pass all ArrayList into the Runnable's constructor or just create as many Runnable instances as ArrayLists you have and start them in the required order/parallelism.

Comment: Also, instead of extending `Thread` class, rather implement `Runnable` interface and use `ExecutorService`